# Is it wise to define a "catchall" for a flags-type enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I have an `enum` that is declared in the following manner (but with more options - about 15 or so) since I wanted an easy way to define all options without having to explicitly list them.

```
[Flags]
enum Options
{
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2,
    Option3 = 4,
    Option4 = 8,
    AllOptions = 15
}
```

So that instead of saying

```
Options foo = Options.Option1 | Options.Option2 | Options.Option3 |... ad nauseum
```

I can just say

```
Options foo = Options.AllOptions;
```

Is this wise? Or is there perhaps a better way to give a variable all available options without explicitly having to list them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Or is there perhaps a better way to give a variable all available options without explicitly having to list them?

Well, you could use my [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) project:

```
Options allOptions = Flags.GetUsedBits<Options>();
```

(There are then all kinds of other operations you can do using Unconstrained Melody.)

Personally I'd try to avoid hard-coding an "all" value though - it would be all too easy to add a new value and forget to update the "all" value.

(I'd also avoid naming it `AllOptions` in this case - it should just be `All`, to avoid the redundancy in `Options.AllOptions`.)

If you *do* do it, add a unit test to make sure you've done it right :)

Comment: I like the Unconstrained Melody idea, especially the fact that adding more options to the list will be automatically included in the `allOptions` variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
[Flags]
enum Options
{
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2,
    Option3 = 4,
    Option4 = 8,
    AllOptions = Option1 | Option2 | Option3 | Option4
}
```

This approach literally means Option1 and Option2 and Option3 and Option4. You can use this as:

```
Options.AllOptions;
```

or

```
Options.Option1 | Options.Option2 | Options.Option3 | Option.Option4
```

Both of the above will end up as the same result.